# Why won't to run my script for every sheet in excel file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spreadsheet, pandas-datareader

Why won't to run my script for every sheet in excel file? I wrote a script to run on my excel and it worked perfectly until I added `sheet_name=None`, see the simplified version of my script.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
new_data = df.stack(0)
new_data1 = new_data.eval('C = A + B')
new_data2 = new_data1.eval('C = A / B')
new_data2.to_excel('multisheet.xlsx')
```

When I run a got an error in third line, see an error!

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-7cc1bc9021ef> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])
----> 3 df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
      4 new_data = df.stack(0)
      5 new_data1 = new_data.eval('C = A + B')

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

I tried to solve this like this...

```
import pandas as pd
dff = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])
for name, df in dff.items():
    df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
    new_data = df.stack(0)
    new_data1 = new_data.eval('C = A + B')
    new_data2 = new_data1.eval('C = A / B')
    new_data2.to_excel('multisheet.xlsx')
```

In the end, it will only run a script for my last sheet. But I need to run for all sheet and to keep a name of sheets. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `sheet_name=None`, `df` is not a dataframe but a dict of dataframe where keys are the sheet name.

From the documentation:

> Returns DataFrame or dict of DataFrames
>
> DataFrame from the passed in Excel file. See notes in sheet_name argument for more information on when a dict of DataFrames is returned.

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('Data1.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
```

```
>>> type(dfs)
dict

>>> dfs.keys()
dict_keys(['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'])

>>> dfs['Sheet1']
   id first_name   last_name
0   1    Roxanna  Calderbank
1   2       Hali   Kilmartin
2   3       Moss      Hatzar
3   4       Kari    Giordano
4   5      Dylan     Witnall
```

Comment: This explains a lot. Is it possible to create function that reads dfs.keys() and running a script for every sheet without manually reading and inputting  keys?

Comment: Try: `for key, df in dfs.items(): ...`

Comment: Can you help me with rest? All I tried is not working properly :/

Comment: I can help you but I need a plain text sample of a sheet of your dataframe.

Comment: Do you want me to edit a question, make a new one or sent some other way?

Comment: Actually, the current question is "why ..." and the solution answers to this question. Therefore, I propose you to create a new question but don't forget to post sample, copy / paste what you have try so far and the expected result. So, don't forget to accept answer if this one answered to your question.

Comment: And please, notify me  here when you have asked the question so I won't miss it.

Comment: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68700107/trying-to-run-python-pandas-script-for-every-sheet-in-document-with-sheet-name-n) to new question is here.