# Trying to run python pandas script for every sheet in document with sheet_name=None but not working

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, spreadsheet

For days I'm trying to solve a problem which I have with `sheet_name=None`, however everything I tried is not working. I need to read a excel document and run this for every sheet in document and to keep names of sheet (and I don't know sheet names). I have tried something like this

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('products2.xlsx', sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])
for name, df in dfs.items():
```

but only helped me to avoid first error, but it doesn't run for every sheet, only last one.

Also, found different solutions online but there are not keeping sheet separated, I need to keep sheets and sheetnames.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns


df = pd.read_excel('products2.xlsx', index_col=[0], sheet_name=None)

df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)

new_data = df.stack(0)
new_data1 = new_data.eval('status = profit - loss + other')
new_data2 = new_data1.eval('index = (profit / status) / (loss / status)')

output = new_data2.unstack(1).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
order = output.reindex(columns=['profit', 'loss', 'other', 'status', 'index'], level=1)

rounding = order.round(3)

cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
cc = sns.light_palette("red", as_cmap=True)
pc = sns.color_palette("vlag", as_cmap=True)
styler = rounding.style  # Keep Styler for reuse
green = styler.background_gradient(
    cmap=cm,
    subset=rounding.columns.get_loc_level('profit', level=1)[0]
)
red = green.background_gradient(
    cmap=cc,
    subset=rounding.columns.get_loc_level('loss', level=1)[0]
)

styler.to_excel('output_file.xlsx')
```

If someone can help me find solution, here is [Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/x0yol7hdgsd1qi60s2ud0/products2.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=2u1d42cqx6846edsez8fwfv1f) of excel document.

Comment: Have you tried looping the sheets? `import pandas as pd

dfs = []
ex_file = pd.ExcelFile('products2.xlsx')

for sheet in ex_file.sheet_names:
    #do something
    df = ...
    dfs.append(df)
`

Comment: If you use `to_excel` without `sheet_name`, you override the default sheet. To avoid to reopen the excel file at each loop, use an `ExcelWriter object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.ExcelWriter` to create a new file and `to_excel` to write on different sheet:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

dfs = pd.read_excel('products2.xlsx', sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])

with pd.ExcelWriter('output_file.xlsx') as writer:  # <- HERE
    for name, df in dfs.items():
        print(name)
        df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
        new_data = df.stack(0)
        new_data1 = new_data.eval('status = profit - loss + other')
        new_data2 = new_data1.eval('index = (profit / status) / (loss / status)')

        output = new_data2.unstack(1).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
        order = output.reindex(columns=['profit', 'loss', 'other', 'status', 'index'], level=1)

        rounding = order.round(3)

        cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
        cc = sns.light_palette("red", as_cmap=True)
        pc = sns.color_palette("vlag", as_cmap=True)
        styler = rounding.style  # Keep Styler for reuse
        green = styler.background_gradient(
            cmap=cm,
            subset=rounding.columns.get_loc_level('profit', level=1)[0]
        )
        red = green.background_gradient(
            cmap=cc,
            subset=rounding.columns.get_loc_level('loss', level=1)[0]
        )

        styler.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)  # <- HERE
```

First sheet:
[image: first sheet]

Second sheet:
[image: second sheet]